# How do I cast ENUMs to their integer values when selecting into an outfile in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, enums

Description is basically the question.

I have a CSV file that I load into a table in my database. I then (SELECT * FROM tablename into OUTFILE '...') and check that the two CSVs are equal. I do this to make sure that the database was loaded properly.

My problem is that one of the fields is an ENUM type. The CSV I use to load the table contains the integer representation (for reasons I can't control) and the outfile CSV contains the string representation. Is there any way for me to cast the ENUM into its integer value when creating the outfile? I feel as though this should be an easy thing to do but I wasn't able to find an answer on Google.

Note: I have to do this for many different tables so it's difficult for me to treat each table on an individual basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a numeric context to get the enum's integer value. Try this:

```
SELECT ..., enum_field+0, ...
```

This will evaluate the enum_field in a numeric context, which will return the index value.

Comment: Okay, thanks, this solution works. However, I am trying to do this for multiple tables automatically, and doing this requires me to treat each table differently than the next. (ie SELECT ... table1_enum_field ...) then another statement with SELECT ... table2_enum_field ... Is there any way to better automate this?

Comment: @nikhil.narula Unforrunately, I don't know of a way to automatically test the fields type and then apply different action to the field in the select (like in a case statement or such).  If you are writing this as a multi-line SQL script you could possibly look at the information schema data to get information about the row type and then do the operation mentioned above to those filed names that are enum.